# Where is the city of Ninveh?

Tags: tanach, geography

Ninveh is mentioned in the book of Yona that is read on Yom Kippur. Where is Ninveh?

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineveh:

> Nineveh was an ancient Assyrian city on the eastern bank of the Tigris River, and capital of the Neo-Assyrian Empire. Its ruins are across the river from the modern-day major city of Mosul, in the Ninawa Governorate of Iraq.

Comment: Any evidence that that's the same city as is mentioned in _Yona_?

Comment: @msh210 It's the only city of that name that Wikipedia knows about in the area, and it was a big and famous city as the capital of Assyria (Ashur). Wikipedia also explicitly labels it as such http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineveh#Biblical_Nineveh and I see no reason to assume otherwise.